Where are the default `.colors` files stored in KDE Plasma 6?
.colours files created or imported using kcm_colors are stored in $HOME/.local/share/color-schemes/. However, this doesn't include the myriad default themes that are considered to be part of the default package selection, like those contained in the breeze package. Where are these stored?

Asked at https://discuss.kde.org/t/where-are-the-default-colors-files-stored-in-kde-plasma-6/19873?u=rokejulianlockhart too.

They are at /usr/share/color-schemes/ in KDE Plasma 6.1.3. [1]
